# Unable to push changes via git behind Proxy with Heroku

Tags: git, heroku, push

I set up the git proxy settings using `git config --global http.proxy "http://username:password@proxy:port"`, but when I do `git push heroku master` it raises `fatal: unable to access 'https://git.heroku.com/myrepo.git/': Recv failure: Connection was reset`

I don't understand why this happens. I did not make any changes, and this used to work a couple of days ago.

Comment: Not much we can tell you based on this... is the proxy working otherwise? Are you sure your configuration is still correct?

Comment: Yes, my proxy is a school proxy, the internet works...The configuration is correct, the exact same procedure, without proxy, works at home perfectly fine.